# How to prove this inequality of Gamma function

Tags: number-theory

As I was studying the properties of gamma function I saw this website https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/introductions/Gamma/05/ there are 3 special properties of gamma function given in link.And I want to proof of first one among those 3 i.e $|\Gamma(z)|\leq|\Gamma(\Re z)|$.

Comment: Hint: Try to show that $$
\left| {\frac{{\Gamma (\Re z)}}{{\Gamma (z)}}} \right|^2  = \prod\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {1 + \left( {\frac{{\Im z}}{{\Re z + n}}} \right)^2 } \right)} 
$$ whenever $\Re z \neq 0,-1,-2,\ldots$.

Comment: What did you try? When $\Re z > 0$, it is straightforward using the integral definition since $|t^{x+iy}| \leq t^x$

Comment: Oh sorry ! I completely forgot about integral I was looking up at all other definitions. And thank you for helping me LL 3.14